# Spyder debug mode not working in Anaconda root environment

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, zeromq, spyder

I am learning python using Anaconda, Whenever I am trying to run spyder debug mode in Anaconda root env. I always get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       debugfile('/home/.../project2.py', wdir='/home/.../Project_2', post_mortem=True)
>
> File
>   "/home/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py",
>   line 809, in debugfile
>       debugger.run("runfile(%r, args=%r, wdir=%r)" % (filename, args, wdir))
>
> File "/home/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/bdb.py", line 434, in run
>       exec(cmd, globals, locals)
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File
>   "/home/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py",
>   line 786, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "/home/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py",
>   line 110, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "/home/.../project2.py", line 2, in 
>       import pandas as pd
>
> File "/home/.../project2.py", line 2, in 
>       import pandas as pd
>
> File "/home/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/bdb.py", line 51, in
>   trace_dispatch
>       return self.dispatch_line(frame)
>
> File "/home/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/bdb.py", line 69, in
>   dispatch_line
>       self.user_line(frame)
>
> File "/home/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pdb.py", line 261, in user_line
>       self.interaction(frame, None)
>
> File
>   "/home/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py",
>   line 425, in interaction
>       self._cmdloop()
>
> File
>   "/home/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py",
>   line 436, in _cmdloop
>       self.cmdloop()
>
> File "/home/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/cmd.py", line 126, in cmdloop
>       line = input(self.prompt)
>
> File
>   "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py",
>   line 853, in raw_input
>       password=False,
>
> File
>   "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py",
>   line 863, in _input_request
>       self.stdin_socket.recv_multipart(zmq.NOBLOCK)
>
> File
>   "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/sugar/socket.py",
>   line 467, in recv_multipart
>       parts = [self.recv(flags, copy=copy, track=track)]
>
> File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 788, in
>   zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.recv
>
> File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 824, in
>   zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.recv
>
> File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 191, in
>   zmq.backend.cython.socket._recv_copy
>
> File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 186, in
>   zmq.backend.cython.socket._recv_copy
>
> File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 19, in
>   zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc
>
> Again: Resource temporarily unavailable

I keep my Anaconda updated, but the debug mode runs normally in my another virtual env (my_env),

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- root_env (python 3.6.8), my_env (python 3.7.2)
- spyder: 3.3.3 (both)
- IPython: 7.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Reading carefully your traceback, it seems you're mixing Anaconda packages with packages you installed in your home directory with pip. And those are incompatible for binary packages like `pyzmq`, the one generating the error.

So you need to remove this directory

`~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

to avoid the mixing and fix your problem.

Comment: hello, just added the bug fix modification in the link you provided, but the problem is still there...

Comment: well, does that mean it will remove all packages installed with pip? I have some pip installed packages in root env and I need those packages

Comment: As I said, you can't mix binary pip and conda packages (like pyzmq). It's fine for pure Python packages though (like Flask). So it's up to you how to fix this problem.

Comment: If you consider my answer solved your problem (or help you to do it), please mark it as so by selecting the green check mark on the left.